# Why may class which contains "typedef" defined in different parts lead to error?

Tags: c++11, typedef, incomplete-type

I'm using "typedef" in class definition, but when this class happens in different positions, it performs differently and may lead to an error. Please help me check the following code.

This version of code may cause an error:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
class B;
class A 
{
    public: 
        A() { }
        std::vector<B::size_type> vec;
};
class B
{
    public: 
        typedef std::vector<std::string>::size_type size_type; // [Error] incomplete type 'B' used in nested name specifier
};
```

But the following code runs normally:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
class B
{
    public: 
        typedef std::vector<std::string>::size_type size_type;
};
class A 
{
    public: 
        A() { }
        std::vector<B::size_type> vec;
};
```

Comment: Because the code gets parsed in order (top to bottom). In the first version B is only forward declared and the typedef is not known. In the second version B is complete before the typedef is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not in the `typedef` itself, but in the order of defining.

In the first code snippet, the compiler does not know what is this `B::size_type` - it only knows, that a `class B` exists. In the latter case, the compiler already knows your `typedef`, hence `B::size_type`.

This happens, because the compiler "reads" (parses) the code line by line and the order of definition matters.

Comment: What else can I do to avoid this kind of error besides adjusting the sequence of class defining? Using friend class?

Comment: @Vogel_guo - no, you can't do anything. Maybe splitting the classes in different headers, but then the `include`s are important in the same way. The order of defining symbols is important. Also, these errors are compile time, so they are not dangerous in any way (during run-time)

Comment: Ok, I think I understand it now after your explanation, thank you.